# jupyter notebook markdown: add results of math operation in markdown cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

How can I add the printed results of math operation in the markdown cell? I tried this but didn't work:

```
`print(32750-25797)` patients dropped in step 2
```

I get

```
print(32750-25797) patients dropped in step 2
```

But I want this output:

```
6953 patients dropped in step 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [Python Markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown#python-markdown) extension of the [Jupyter Notebook Extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).

Answer (score 0):

Markdowns are used to write mathematical equations. they don't solve mathematical equations. They only display it as a comment.